# asset_path not displaying image in pdf generated template in rails 7

Tags: pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, ruby-on-rails-7

I am using wkhtmltopdf gem for pdf generation , now the issue i am facing is that logo is displaying in pdf template file but when i generate the pdf logo doesnot shows up, while logo is present in assets/images directory.
below is code for image:
`<div class="logo center"> <img src="<%= asset_path('pcm_logo.png') %>" alt="PCM Logo"> </div>`